# How to list applications and get the currently selected one within Node.JS

Tags: node.js

As the title suggests, I need to find a way to get the list of running applications (atom, chrome, etc.).  I am currently using:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec

exec('tasklist', (error, stdout, stderr) {
  // stdout contains a list of running processes.
})
```

However this also gives services and hidden applications (redis-server, etc.) and doesn't return whether or not the window is currently active or not.  Is there a way for this to be done?  For reference, this is for a Windows system, but a cross-operating system solution would be preferable.

Answer (score 1):

I found the wonderful [winctl](https://github.com/thraaawn/winctl) library allowed me to do what I needed.  I used the following code:

```
const winctl = require('winctl')

// Iterate over all windows with a custom filter
winctl.FindWindows(win => win.isVisible() && win.getTitle()).then(windows => {
    console.log("Visible windows:");
    windows.sort((a,b) => a.getTitle().localeCompare(b.getTitle())).forEach(window => console.log(" - %s [pid=%d, hwnd=%d, parent=%d]", window.getTitle(), window.getPid(), window.getHwnd(), window.getParent()));
});
```

Comment: this doesn't build anymore

Comment: it requires Visual Studio? `Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use`